# All 12V outlets lose power until restart

Tags: toyota, power-outlet, air-compressor

I have a 2010 Toyota Sequoia limited 5.7L V8. I have 4-120W 12V Outlets. I am trying to use the same air compressor to fill a tire that I have been using for several years and never had a problem. Now, when I plug it in, I get power to the compressor but as soon as I flip the on switch to start pumping, I lose all power to all of my 12V outlets. I can turn the car off then back on and the 12V outlets have power again but the same issue continues to occur. Each 12v outlet has it's own fuse and none were blown. I also have an accessories relay which might be the problem. The problem occurs whether the engine is running or not and my batter is a fairly new Northstar AGM. I then used the pump in my wife's Explorer and it works fine. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen regardless of whether the car engine is running? What if you jump your wife's explorer to your Sequoia and then try? Obviously something changed. Either the Sequoia battery got weaker, or the compressor started consuming more current at startup, or the over-current protection mechanism in your SUV got more sensitive. Don't reply in the comments. Add the information to your original question by editing it.

Comment: The compressor is overloading the circuit. I would bet as the compressor has gotten older, it draws more current (as mkeith suggests).

Comment: So I should have mentioned that all four 12v outlets went out at the same time and each outlet has its own fuse. There is also an accessories relay which is why I thought if they all shut off without blowing any fuses it might be the relay? It happens regardless of whether the car is running or not. The battery is healthy and relatively new. It's a Northstar AGM that's far better than any lead acid I've owned. Haven't been able to jump to wife's car and test yet.

Comment: Did you check power wiring to these 12v outlets back to battery?